# Custom Notifications android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to create a custom status bar notification in Android that has a button or image in addition to the text. The button should do a different task. I used setOnClickPendingIntent to register a task to be performed on button click. But it calls the contentIntent for the main notification instead of the one registered for the button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post code here that you have done so far?